# Forwarding traffic from pod to service running on localhost

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

My k8 cluster runs on minikube.

I am familiar with kubectl port-forward command which allows to route traffic from localhost into the cluster.

Is there a way do do it the other way around? Can I route the traffic from one of the pods to the web server that runs locally on my machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to connect from your `minikube` pod to your host will heavily depend on the type of `--driver` you used.

Each `--driver` could alter the way to connect from your pod to your host. What I mean is that there could be multiple options for each `--driver` to connect to your host.

As pointed by user @Srikrishna B H

> Make sure you use local machine IP instead of `localhost` while connecting to web server running locally in your machine.

I've created 3 examples:

- Ubuntu with `minikube start --driver=docker`
- Mac OS with `minikube start --driver=hyperkit`
- Windows with `minikube start --driver=virtualbox`

> **IP addresses used below are only for example purposes!**

---

#### Ubuntu with Docker

Assuming that you have an Ubuntu machine with Docker installed and `nginx` working as a server that your pod will connect to:

- `$ minikube start --driver=docker`
- `$ ip addr show`:

  - `docker0` - docker interface
  - `ensX` - "physical" interface

Above command will tell you the IP address to connect from your pod (on host)

```sh
2: ensX: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    <----> 
    inet 10.0.0.2/32 scope global dynamic ensX 
    <---->
```

```sh
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    <---->
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
    <---->
```

Then you can spawn a pod to check if you can connect to your nginx:

- `$ kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh`
- `$ wget -q0 - IP_ADDRESS` - `busybox` image doesn't have `curl` installed

  - `172.17.0.1`
  - `10.0.0.2`

---

#### Mac OS with Hyperkit

Assuming that you have a Mac OS machine and you have configured `nginx` on port `8080`:

- `$ minikube start --driver=hyperkit`
- `$ ifconfig`:

  - `bridge100`
  - `enX` - "physical" interface

> Disclaimer!
>
> You will need to allow connections to your nginx outside of `localhost` in the firewall or completely disable it (not recommended!)

```sh
bridge100: flags=8a63<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,ALLMULTI,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    <---->
    inet 192.168.64.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.64.255
    <---->
```

```sh
enX: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    <----> 
    inet 192.168.1.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255 
    <---->
```

Then you can spawn a pod to check if you can connect to your nginx:

- `$ kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh`
- `$ wget -q0 - IP_ADDRESS` - `busybox` image doesn't have `curl` installed

  - `192.168.64.1:8080`
  - `192.168.1.101:8080`

---

#### Windows with Virtualbox

When you create a `minikube` instance with `--driver=virtualbox` in Windows, it creates a `VM` with 2 network interfaces:

- `NAT` - used to communicate with outside (Internet)
- `Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter` - used to communicate between `minikube` and your host

Assuming that you have a Windows machine with Virtualbox, you have configured `nginx` on port `80` and also you have a running `minikube` instance.

You will need to get the IP addresses of (`$ ipconfig`) :

- Your "physical" interface (`Ethernet X` for example)
- Your `Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter`

```bsh
Ethernet adapter Ethernet X:
   <----> 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

```bsh
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #X:
   <---> 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.99.1 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

> Disclaimer!
>
> You will need check if your firewall will accept the traffic destined for ngin (If it's not blocked).

Then you can spawn a pod to check if you can connect to your nginx:

- `$ kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh`
- `$ wget -q0 - IP_ADDRESS` - `busybox` image doesn't have `curl` installed

  - `192.168.99.1`
  - `192.168.1.3`

Comment: Regarding MacOS instructions, what command do I actually run? Something like `ifconfig bridge100 enX`? Is `enX` a placeholder for one of `en0`, `en1`, ...? How do I know which one (I have en0 ... en4).

Comment: @GreenGiant it will depend on the `driver` that you are using. For example with `hyperkit` you will be using `bridge100` to connect from your pod to your host. `ifconfig` is only to show the network interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by default you can route traffic from your pod to the local machine.
make sure you use local machine IP instead of `localhost` while connecting to web server running locally in your machine.