# Forward traffic from Kubernetes pod to local server

Tags: kubernetes

How can I forward traffic from a remote Kubernetes pod to a server running on my local machine? The intention is to test a remote server making calls to a service running on my local machine. I've used `kubectl port-forward` to forward traffic from my local service to remote service, but I need to do this the other way around.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63885761/2233706) is for minikube, which is used to run Kubernetes locally, so this probably doesn't apply to me.

Answer (score 9):

There's probably a "more K8s" way, but here's an idea in case you don't find anything better - use ssh.

Specifically, set up and expose SSH on the pod so it's accessible from your local machine. Then just use ssh on your machine to create a [remote ssh tunnel](https://robotmoon.com/ssh-tunnels/#remote-port-forwarding).

For instance `ssh -R 8080:localhost:80 <exposed-pod-ssh>` will forward the pod's localhost:8080 to your local machine port 80.

Comment: Oh my god, this is easier! But needs sshd ou something like that on the pod.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: Some guys use https://github.com/omrikiei/ktunnel instead of SSH. In some cases it is quite difficult to install OpenSSH's sshd because you may have no a package manager (pamac, apt, yum) in your system, at all. So, you can't install ssh from a source because you need to install all its dependencies first.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very annoying task.

With nothing special on hands, you need to redirect a port from your modem to your machine.
Most of people have non-fixed public ips, so you need to find your public ip address (you cant search for "what is my ip") and hope that it don't change between your tests.
With your public ip address you can try to access directly from pod, ex:

```
kubectl exec -ti alpine-pod -- curl 150.136.143.228:8080
```

Some clusters don't let the pod go outside from their own, so, better create an **service** without selectors and then add the an **endpoint** pointing to your ip:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: to-my-home
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

Then, add the **endpoint**:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: to-my-home
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 150.136.143.228
    ports:
      - port: 8080
```

Now, if you're inside in the same namespace that service, you cand do this:

```
kubectl exec -ti alpine-pod -- curl to-my-home
```

An better, and easy, solution is to use **vagrant share**, https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share, but you need some steps:

1. Install an hypervisor (VirtualBox, Libvirt, HyperV, VMWare)
2. Install Vagrant
3. Create and account on https://app.vagrantup.com
4. Start a machine and use **vagrant share**
5. Grab the URL showed on command return and use on pod/service, the port is always 80

Example:

```
vagrant init debian/buster64
vagrant login
vagrant up
vagrant share
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mesh vpn for this. Something like https://tailscale.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not a "k8s" way of doing so but I used nc inside of the pod to see http requests sent from the pod to a remote service.

For that,

- I hanged the url of the remote service to http://localhost:9091 in the app configs within the running pod
- then, started nc in the pod listening at 9091: `nc -l -p 9091`

Once you trigger the pod to send a request to the remote service, nc will print that request